# Centos - Can not remove file as Root (no error, nothing)

Tags: linux, centos

as stated in title, I cannot remove file from centos as the root user.

```
rm filename.php
rm: remove regular empty file ‘filename.php’? y
```

Nothing happens, file still in place

OS: CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

I tried

```
rm -f
```

I also tried

`find -name .... -delete` .

I also checked `dmesg` and nothing related there.

I also made a new file in same directory and remove it without any problems.

**UPDATE.** I can edit this file, but once I try to remove it, file becomes empty but still there.

I checked if this file is used by any processes and its not.

Comment: From your update, looks like something is recreating the file.

Comment: Could it be Kernel bug ?

Comment: Can you include outputs of `ls -la filename.php` & `lsattr filename.php`?